# WebRTC Connection fails

Tags: android, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I have already installed RTCMultiConnection from : https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection 
It works on PC IOS and some Android systems
but while Android connects with laptop for joining video chat, laptop's user can't see video.
The laptop log message shows : `remote peer sdp ... a = recvonly.`
is there anything Android setting I can do to changing from 'recvonly' to 'sendrecv',
 Thank so much.

```
Remote peer's sdp: 
v=0
o=- 4505484166719341685 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video data
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 0 8 105 13 110 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:JVcK
a=ice-pwd:4whuQgU0B4Mf8+TBngcaQx43
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7A:E9:80:7D:77:6A:6C:4C:03:D9:94:DC:B1:CD:3E:10:91:7D:52:6F:C6:86:A2:3B:02:2D:2B:40:D9:7D:6E:B9
a=setup:active
a=mid:audio
b=AS:128
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1; stereo=1; sprop-stereo=1; stereo=1; sprop-stereo=1; maxaveragebitrate=1024000; maxplaybackrate=1024000; stereo=1; sprop-stereo=1; stereo=1; sprop-stereo=1; maxaveragebitrate=1024000; maxplaybackrate=1024000
a=maxptime:3
a=maxptime:3
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 102 123 108 109 124
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:JVcK
a=ice-pwd:4whuQgU0B4Mf8+TBngcaQx43
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7A:E9:80:7D:77:6A:6C:4C:03:D9:94:DC:B1:CD:3E:10:91:7D:52:6F:C6:86:A2:3B:02:2D:2B:40:D9:7D:6E:B9
a=setup:active
a=mid:video
b=AS:300
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=fmtp:96 x-google-min-bitrate=256; x-google-max-bitrate=256
a=fmtp:96 x-google-min-bitrate=256; x-google-max-bitrate=256
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:123 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:123 apt=102
a=rtpmap:108 red/90000
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 ulpfec/90000
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:JVcK
a=ice-pwd:4whuQgU0B4Mf8+TBngcaQx43
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7A:E9:80:7D:77:6A:6C:4C:03:D9:94:DC:B1:CD:3E:10:91:7D:52:6F:C6:86:A2:3B:02:2D:2B:40:D9:7D:6E:B9
a=setup:active
a=mid:data
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
```